Processing large dataset using streamlit in snowflake is extremely slow. How to process large pandas dataset on the fly using Streamlit in snowflake?
I have a usecase where I have to create a Streamlit App which will load the files from an internal named stage into a dataframe. Once the dataframe is loaded it should be displayed on the streamlit UI using st.dataframe() and a user must be able to filter the data or drop columns from the dataframe displayed. Once he drops columns or filters the dataframe, the UI should display the updated dataframe. I have completed the functional requirements and they are working perfectly fine with less data(around 1 mb) but it is extremely slow or not responding for data around 74mb. I am using L warehouse. How can I improve performance?
# Import python packages
import streamlit as st
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session
from snowflake.snowpark.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, FloatType, DataType
#from st_aggrid import AgGrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer
import plotly.express as px
from pandas.api.types import (
    is_categorical_dtype,
    is_datetime64_any_dtype,
    is_numeric_dtype,
    is_object_dtype,
)

# Write directly to the app
st.set_page_config(
        page_title="User360 Analytics",
        page_icon=":rocket:",
        layout="wide"
    )

st.write("### Customer Segmentation Using Clustering")

# Get the current credentials
session = get_active_session()

def filter_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Adds a UI on top of a dataframe to let viewers filter columns

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): Original dataframe

    Returns:
        pd.DataFrame: Filtered dataframe
    """
    modify = st.checkbox("Add filters")

    if not modify:
        return df

    df = df.copy()

    # Try to convert datetimes into a standard format (datetime, no timezone)
    for col in df.columns:
        if is_object_dtype(df[col]):
            try:
                df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
            except Exception:
                pass

        if is_datetime64_any_dtype(df[col]):
            df[col] = df[col].dt.tz_localize(None)

    modification_container = st.container()

    with modification_container:
        to_filter_columns = st.multiselect("Filter dataframe on", df[['PRODUCT_TYPE','FORMER_CUSTOMER_FLAG','FIRST_FUND_FLAG','ACQUISITION_CHANNEL','ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_FLAG']].columns)
        for column in to_filter_columns:
            left, right = st.columns((1, 20))
            left.write("↳")
            # Treat columns with < 10 unique values as categorical
            if is_categorical_dtype(df[column]) or df[column].nunique() < 10:
                user_cat_input = right.multiselect(
                    f"Values for {column}",
                    df[column].unique(),
                    default=list(df[column].unique()),
                )
                df = df[df[column].isin(user_cat_input)]
            elif is_numeric_dtype(df[column]):
                _min = float(df[column].min())
                _max = float(df[column].max())
                step = (_max - _min) / 100
                user_num_input = right.slider(
                    f"Values for {column}",
                    _min,
                    _max,
                    (_min, _max),
                    step=step,
                )
                df = df[df[column].between(*user_num_input)]
            elif is_datetime64_any_dtype(df[column]):
                user_date_input = right.date_input(
                    f"Values for {column}",
                    value=(
                        df[column].min(),
                        df[column].max(),
                    ),
                )
                if len(user_date_input) == 2:
                    user_date_input = tuple(map(pd.to_datetime, user_date_input))
                    start_date, end_date = user_date_input
                    df = df.loc[df[column].between(start_date, end_date)]
            else:
                user_text_input = right.text_input(
                    f"Substring or regex in {column}",
                )
                if user_text_input:
                    df = df[df[column].str.contains(user_text_input)]
        to_drop_columns = st.multiselect("Drop columns", df.columns)
        if to_drop_columns:
            df = df.drop(columns=to_drop_columns)
    return df

def load_data():
    columns = [
        ("ACCOUNT_ID", StringType()),
        ("PRODUCT_TYPE", StringType()),
        ("LOAD_DELAY_MEAN", FloatType()),
        ("WITHDRAWAL_DELAY_MEAN", FloatType()),
        ("FIRST_FUND_DELAY", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_LOAD_CNT", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_WITHDRAW_CNT", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_LOAD_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_WITHDRAW_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_CREDIT_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_DEBIT_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("SAVINGS_DEPOSIT_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("ACH_DEBIT_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("P2P_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("FEES_PAID", IntegerType()),
        ("ACH_DEPOSIT_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("LOAD_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("SAVINGS_WITHDRAWAL_AMT", IntegerType()),
        ("VISA_ORIGINAL_CREDIT_TRANSACTION", IntegerType()),
        ("NETWORK_BASED_CREDIT_TRANSACTION", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_CREDIT_CNT", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_DEBIT_CNT", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT", IntegerType()),
        ("FORMER_CUSTOMER_FLAG", IntegerType()),
        ("DEBIT_30_ACTIVE_FLAG", IntegerType()),
        ("DAY_30_SURVIVAL_FLAG", IntegerType()),
        ("DAY_90_SURVIVAL_FLAG", IntegerType()),
        ("DAY_30_FUND", IntegerType()),
        ("DAY_90_FUND", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_FEE_AMOUNT", IntegerType()),
        ("TOTAL_INTERCHANGE_AMOUNT", IntegerType()),
        ("FIRST_FUND_FLAG", IntegerType()),
        ("DIRECTDEPOSIT_CNT", IntegerType()),
        ("ACQUISITION_CHANNEL", StringType()),
        ("ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_FLAG", StringType())
    ]

    # Create a schema struct type
    schema = StructType([StructField(name, dataType) for name, dataType in columns])
    #df = session.read.options({"field_delimiter": ",", "skip_header": 1}).schema(schema).csv("@sandbox.io_dev.preprocessed_files/cust_features_1.csv")
    df = session.read.options({"field_delimiter": ",", "skip_header": 1, "pattern": ".*[.]csv"}).schema(schema).csv("@sandbox.io_dev.preprocessed_files")
    df.collect()
    df_user_feat = df.toPandas()
    return df_user_feat

def data_scaling(data_for_scale):

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    #df_numerical = df_trans.drop('PRODUCT_TYPE',axis = 1)
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data_for_scale[data_for_scale.columns])
    df_scaled_data = pd.DataFrame(data=scaled_data, columns=data_for_scale.columns)
    return df_scaled_data

def main():
    cluster_container = st.container()
    with cluster_container:
        df_event_data = load_data()
        df_filter_data = filter_dataframe(df_event_data)
        st.dataframe(df_filter_data)
        col_kmeans,col_kmeans_1 = st.columns(2)
        with col_kmeans:
            st.write("###### Use this section to run KMeans clustering on the data")
            st.write("###### Enter the value you want to cluster the customers on. If you are not sure, leave it as 0 and the system will find the optimal value for you.")
            #user_input = st.text_input("Enter the number of clusters", "0")
            user_input = st.slider('Select number of clusters', min_value=0, max_value=10, value=0)
        if st.button('Run clustering for current sheet'):
            
            df_for_plotting = df_filter_data.copy()
            df_for_plotting.drop('ACQUISITION_CHANNEL', axis=1,inplace = True)
            df_scaled_data = data_scaling(df_for_plotting[df_for_plotting.columns[2:]])
            #print(df_for_plotting.head(10))
            if user_input != 0:
                n_clusters = int(user_input)
            else:
                model = KMeans()
                visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(1,10))
                visualizer.fit(df_scaled_data)
                optimal_k = visualizer.elbow_value_
                n_clusters= optimal_k
            kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters,random_state=0 )
            kmeans.fit(df_scaled_data)
            df_scaled_data['clusters'] = kmeans.labels_
            df_for_plotting['clusters'] = kmeans.labels_
            cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_ 
            columns = df_scaled_data.columns[:-1]
            df_centers = pd.DataFrame(cluster_centers, columns=columns)
            # Add a 'Cluster' column to the DataFrame
            df_centers['Cluster'] = [f'Cluster {label}' for label in range(0, len(cluster_centers))]
            # Melt the DataFrame for easier plotting
            df_melted = pd.melt(df_centers, id_vars=['Cluster'], value_vars=columns, var_name='Feature', value_name='Value')
            #cluster_plot(df_for_plotting)
            col2, col3 = st.columns(2)
            
            col5,col6 = st.columns(2)
            col4  = st.columns(1)[0]
            with col2:
                fig = px.line_polar(df_melted, r='Value', theta='Feature', line_close=True, color='Cluster',line_dash='Cluster', template='plotly_dark',height = 600,title='Spider Plot for KMeans Clustered Data')
                st.plotly_chart(fig)
            with col3:    
                fig1  = px.line(df_melted, x='Feature', y='Value', line_group='Cluster', color='Cluster',
                                title='Line Plot for KMeans Clustered Data', template='plotly_dark',height = 600)
                st.plotly_chart(fig1)
                
                

            with col5:
                df_lift = pd.merge(df_event_data[['ACCOUNT_ID','ACQUISITION_CHANNEL','FIRST_FUND_FLAG','FORMER_CUSTOMER_FLAG']],df_for_plotting[['ACCOUNT_ID','clusters']],on='ACCOUNT_ID',how='inner')
                #st.session_state.data = 
                st.session_state['clustered_data'] = df_lift
                df_lift_grouped = df_lift.groupby(['clusters','ACQUISITION_CHANNEL','FORMER_CUSTOMER_FLAG']).agg({'ACCOUNT_ID': 'count', 'FIRST_FUND_FLAG': lambda x: sum(x == 1)}).reset_index()
                df_lift_grouped.columns = ['CLUSTERS','ACQUISITION_CHANNEL','FORMER_CUSTOMER_FLAG','CARDS_SENT', 'CARDS_FUNDED']
                st.write("###### Use this section to view the lift in cards sent and funded by cluster and acquisition channel")
                st.write(df_lift_grouped)
                
            with col6:
                fig3 = px.bar(df_lift_grouped, x='CLUSTERS', y=['CARDS_SENT', 'CARDS_FUNDED'], color='ACQUISITION_CHANNEL', barmode='group',title = 'Bar Plot for Cards Sent and Funded by Cluster and Acquisition Channel', template='plotly_dark')
                st.plotly_chart(fig3)
                #df_lift_grouped = df_lift.groupby(['clusters','AQUISITION_CHANNEL','FIRST_FUND_FLAG']).count().reset_index()    

        #st.write("###### Please run clustering before pushing it into Snowflake")
        #st.write("###### On clicking the button, clustered data will be written in the table SANDBOX.IO_DEV.CONSUMER_BEHAVIOUR_CLUSTERING")        
        if st.button("Push Data into snowflake"):
            try:
                clustered_data = st.session_state['clustered_data']
                sp_df_lift = session.create_dataframe(clustered_data)
                #st.write(sp_df_lift.head(30))
                sp_df_lift.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("SANDBOX.IO_DEV.CONSUMER_BEHAVIOUR_CLUSTERING", table_type="transient")
                session.table("SANDBOX.IO_DEV.CONSUMER_BEHAVIOUR_CLUSTERING").collect()
                st.write("Data is now available in snowflake table")
            except:
                st.write("Please run clustering before pusing it into snowflake")

            
                    
            
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    main()
#sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE(INFER_SCHEMA(LOCATION=>'@sandbox.io_dev.preprocessed_files'))";
#sql = 'SELECT t.$1, t.$2 FROM @sandbox.io_dev.preprocessed_files t'
#list_trans = session.sql(sql).collect()
#st.write(list_trans)






I have tried with less data and it is working fine. However, it does not respond for huge dataset.

Are you able to rewrite your logic in Snowpark dataframe, instead of pandas?  The reason you're running into issues is pandas currently requires that the data be loaded into memory on a warehouse in order for it to run the logic.  Snowflake has high-memory warehouses that might work, but the scalability comes from leveraging native Snowflake dataframes, which then become as scalable as a Snowflake table (because they are Snowflake tables).  You can either try high-mem warehouse, rewrite in Snowpark python, or wait for Snowflake to implement Pandas natively.
